# How to set a Port on Pjsip

Tags: android, voip, pjsip

I am implementing a simple VoIP application using PJSIP library. Sending invite message is working but when the other peer sends TRYING msg, it sends on different port instead of the default 5060 as shown in the figure. Is there a way to set it to default 5060 port?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See how pjsua --local-port option is implemented.
But... why would you want to change it? Typically this would be important only for no registration and/or direct IP calls. With fixed listen port you are risking port conflict.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint. I want VoIP-client to send the replay to port 5060 because the SIP  server is listening on port 5060 and it won't get Trying or Ringing messages form the other end client.   Like on the picture I have posted, VoIP cleint is responding to the port 19882 instead of 5060.

Comment: Your server/proxy or other call endpoint seems to be misconfigured. In reality you do not have much control over source port as it may be changed by NAT (perhaps multiple NATs). You can use free sip2sip.info service for testing and it should work. Forcing endpoint to use same port as server shouldn't be ever needed and often would not be possible (think of two softphones running on same PC).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will look at the server configuration.